# SQL MERGE to update or insert values into same table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, merge

```
"MERGE INTO NT_PROPERTY ntProp USING ( "  +
                            "SELECT * FROM NT_PROPERTY ) " +
                            "VALUES " +
                                    "('minDPTObjectId'," + minDPTObjectId + ", 'Starting DPT Object Id') " +
                                    "('maxDPTObjectId', " + maxDPTObjectId + ", 'Ending DPT Object Id') " +
                            "vt (NAME, VALUE, NOTE) " +
                            "ON ( ntProp.NAME = vt.NAME ) " +
                            "WHEN MATCHED THEN " +
                            "UPDATE SET VALUE = vt.VALUE "+
                            "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " +
                            "INSERT (NAME, VALUE, NOTE) VALUES (vt.NAME, vt.VALUE, vt.NOTE)";
```

Well I'm getting a missing ON keyword error and with no clue what so ever, also is there any other way to make it less clumsy

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what type of `minDPTObjectId` and `maxDPTObjectId` int or varchar?

Comment: Just put `PRINT query` (instead of execute) at the end and copy the result into another tab to see how it looks.

Comment: `MERGE INTO NT_PROPERTY ntProp USING ( SELECT * FROM NT_PROPERTY ( VALUES ('minDPTObjectId',9500002785, 'Starting DPT Object Id') ('maxDPTObjectId', 9500002786, 'Ending DPT Object Id') )) vt ( NAME, VALUE, NOTE) ON (ntProp.NAME = vt.NAME) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET VALUE = vt.VALUE WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (NAME, VALUE, NOTE) VALUES (vt.NAME, vt.VALUE, vt.NOTE)` @NenadZivkovic

Comment: @DeepanshuMann There are syntax errors after `FROM nt_property ( values (` First make sure the select query is correct.

Comment: First write a correct MERGE statement in an Oracle client (SQL\*Plus, TOAD, sqlcli, whatever you have to hand). Once you've got the syntax right you can turn it into a JDBC program.

Comment: what that part is? : " +
                            "VALUES " +
                                    "('minDPTObjectId'," + minDPTObjectId + ", 'Starting DPT Object Id') " +
                                    "('maxDPTObjectId', " + maxDPTObjectId + ", 'Ending DPT Object Id') " +
                            "vt (NAME, VALUE, NOTE) " +

Comment: where did you get from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  MERGE INTO NT_PROPERTY D  
      USING (SELECT * FROM DUAL ) S  
      ON (D.NAME = 'minDPTObjectId')  
      WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.VALUE =   '1234' 
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (NAME, VALUE, NOTE) 
      VALUES ('maxDPTObjectId', '1111', 'Ending DPT Object Id') ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your MERGE syntax is incorrect. Your statement takes the form of:

```
MERGE INTO nt_property ntprop
  USING (SELECT * FROM nt_property)
    VALUES (...)
    vt (...)
  ON (ntprop.name = vt.name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ...;
```

but it should be of the form:

```
MERGE INTO target_table tgt_alias
  USING source_table_or_subquery src_alias
    ON (<JOIN conditions>)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ...;
```

Why do you have the `VALUES` and `vt` clauses between your `using` and your `on` clauses? That's the incorrect syntax. Also, whilst you can use `select * from tablename` in the `using` clause, you could just use the tablename directly, since you're selecting all columns and all rows.